# What are the drawbacks to storing a single value as an attribute of a DataFrame instead of as a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I came across some code that calculates a single value, based on a DataFrame, and stores it as an attribute of the DataFrame instead of a separate variable or a new column.

Here's an example. The portfolio has two securities, each with a price and quantity.

```
import pandas

data = {"Prices" : [83.28, 107.38], "Quantities" : [125.926, 7241.531]}
portfolio = pandas.DataFrame(data, index = ["BND", "VTI"], columns = ["Prices", "Quantities"])
portfolio.value = portfolio["Prices"].dot(portfolio["Quantities"])
```

Is there any benefit to storing `value` this way, instead of as a separate variable or a new data column? That is

```
portfolio["Value"] = portfolio["Prices"].dot(portfolio["Quantities"])
```

Technically, the latter may take up more memory because the value is repeated for every observation in the dataset, but in practice, these portfolios have roughly 1000 securities, so it's not an issue.

Assigning the value as an attribute of the DataFrame doesn't survive pickling, but are there any other drawbacks to this? Is there some hidden benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this was a coding error.  I've done this before.

Assume:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1], ['x'])
```

I thought I had:

```
df['y'] = 2
```

But actually didn't.

Later, I:

```
df.y = df.x.sum()
```

Had I actually done `df['y'] = 2`, `df.y` would point to the series `df['y']`.  But because I hadn't, `df.y = df.x.sum()` assigned the scalar sum of `df['x']` to an attribute `y` of `df`.

---

In other words, I see no benefit.